# Is $\ker(f)$ a finitely generated sub-module of $M$ if $\ker(f)\cong M/f(M),f\in \text{End}_R(M)$?

Tags: ring-theory, modules, finitely-generated

Let $M_R$ be a module over a ring $R$ with unit and  $f\in \text{End}_R(M)$.  If $\ker(f)\cong M/f(M)$, then is it right to conclude that $\ker(f)$ is a finitely generated sub-module of $M$?

My thinking is that  $\ker(f)$ is a finitely generated module since each $m\in\ker(f)$ corresponds to some element $m+f(M)\in M/f(M)$.  Moreover, each $m+f(M)$ can be written as a linear combination of $m_1+f(M), m_2+f(M),\ldots,m_n+f(M)$.

Another reason is $M/f(M)$ is a finite module.  So it is finitely generated.

Comment: Are you assuming that $M$ is finitely generated? If you're not assuming this, then you might find a counterexample by letting $M$ be some direct sum of infinitely many copies of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thank you!  I have got.